# Excel Leaving Data Source Workbook Open After Copy/Paste Data Macro is run

Tags: vba, excel

I am very, very new to VBA.
I am trying to automatically copy data through a macro from 8 dynamic "individual" workbooks to paste into one master workbook all layered on 8 tabs as those individual books will be continuously updated by various team members.

I have the macro below which runs fine but excel afterwards leaves the data source workbook open so that won't work with 8 individual files.

What code can I add to tell excel to close the data source file automatically after the micro is ran? Adding "Workbooks("C:\Users\MIRAR\Desktop\AD HOC\DEMO FILE - WIP\SHARNY.xlsx").Close" at the end of the code before End sub is not working and issuing error 9.

Code Below is to copy past data from 1 of the 8 workbooks on 1 tab.

Much appreciated!

```
Sub CopyingRange()
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\MIRAR\Desktop\AD HOC\DEMO FILE - WIP\SHARNY.xlsx"

Dim CopyFromBook As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet

Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks("SHARNY.xlsx")
Set ShToCopy = CopyFromBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set CopyToWbk = Workbooks("Consolidated Tracker File.xlsx")

Workbooks("C:\Users\MIRAR\Desktop\AD HOC\DEMO FILE - WIP\SHARNY.xlsx").Close 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is:

`Workbooks("SHARNY.xlsx").Close`

The better answer is to work with variables that directly point to workbooks:

```
Sub CopyingRange()
    Dim CopyFromBook As Workbook
    Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
    Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet

    Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MIRAR\Desktop\AD HOC\DEMO FILE - WIP\SHARNY.xlsx")
    Set ShToCopy = CopyFromBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set CopyToWbk = Workbooks("Consolidated Tracker File.xlsx")

    CopyFromBook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give you my vote, not because of the indentation, but because you gave the "short" answer too. :D

Comment: BTW - Looking at your profile I guess you must be nearly my vintage - I started using a Trash-80 about a year after I started programming at work.

Comment: I was 9 at the time :D

Comment: 9 when the TRS80 came out?  That means I have a decade on you then, so make sure you respect your elders!!  I was 21 when it came out (checking wikipedia for the release date), which also means that it was released about 3 years after I started programming

Comment: Thank you so very kindly! It worked!!!! I pointed to the variable directly instead of the actual workbook based on the "better" route/practice you have suggested. Just learned something new!

Comment: @Christelle, the best way to thank us is to upvote helpful posts and mark the best answer using the big green checkmark.

Comment: Got it @Excelosaurus! Given that you and @SJR had the same answer, I chose your answer as the best that solved my problem as it was the first one that was posted. :P ..Thanks 4 the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to your workbook variable and use that to close (or any other operation).

```
Sub CopyingRange()

Dim CopyFromBook As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet

Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MIRAR\Desktop\AD HOC\DEMO FILE - WIP\SHARNY.xlsx")
Set ShToCopy = CopyFromBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set CopyToWbk = Workbooks("Consolidated Tracker File.xlsx")

CopyFromBook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: we took the exact same track but _I've_ indented the code in my (updated) answer :P

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used @Excelosaurus answer which matches yours!